# Overlay 2 text elements, whilst vertically centering

Tags: html, css

I am trying to overlay two pieces of text, directly on top of one another to create a layered effect, whilst also trying to vertically centre them in the parent. To vertically centre, I am using a ghost pseudo element as outlined [in this post](https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/), which I find to be the most reliable method when centring in a parent whose height is variable.

As you can see in the fiddle below, the .bg-text element is vertically centered, but the .text-wrapper element is forced to sit below the parent, so it appears this method of vertically centring does not allow for more than one centered element?

```css
figure {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
figure::before {
  content: "[BEFORE]";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em;
}
/* Background text */

.bg-text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 80%;
  color: green;
  text-align: center;
}
/* Text */

.text-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <div class="bg-text">BACKGROUND TEXT</div>
  <div class="text-wrapper">
    <h3>Overlay This</h3>
    <h4>And this!</h4>
  </div>
</figure>
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/f34co15u/2/)

Comment: Overlays require absolute positioning...start there.

Comment: Absolute positioning won't allow vertical centring though?

Comment: Sure it will...

Comment: Thanks for the help @Paulie_D, clearly an important part of the SO community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox and absolute positioning can do that:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
figure {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}
/* Background text */

.bg-text {
  width: 80%;
  color: green;
  text-align: center;
}
/* Text */

.text-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.25);
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <div class="bg-text">BACKGROUND</div>
  <div class="text-wrapper">
    <h3>Overlay This</h3>
    <h4>And this!</h4>
  </div>
</figure>
```

Comment: Brilliant, this is perfect @Paulie_D. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Vertical-align:middle works in table-celll as you not puts. Use this in your style may it's help you

```
.bg-text {
    color: green;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 80%;
}

.text-wrapper {
    color: blue;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 80%;
}
figure {
    background: red none repeat scroll 0 0;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hi, this does help to vertically align both, but doesn't allow them to overlay?